# Creating Win-Loss Records in MySQL with table of scores

Tags: mysql, wordpress

First post here and I'm pretty much a complete noob when it comes to coding, but I've been diving into MySQL and I've built some tables and have been displaying them via my Wordpress site with wpDataTables.

At 37, I've spent most of my life as a journalist with what I'd say average computer skills.

I'm trying to figure out a query that could take a table of college wrestling dual meet scores (State U. 31, Jackson Tech 12) and not only log them, but display their win-loss records. I have not created a master table of all possible schools (although that's not difficult) and we're early enough into the season that I won't get bogged down.

In the past, I used an embed of Google Sheets to display the scores, and then a standings table. Examples below:

Scores: http://www.mattalkonline.com/2015-16-division-i-dual-meet-scores/
Standings: http://www.mattalkonline.com/college-wrestling-standings-15-16/

So .. in short, how the hell do I do this? Can I further break it by conference, division, etc.

Here's a current way how I display the scores page via wpDataTables, which displays via a simple query

www(dot)mattalkonline(dot)com/2016-17-college-dual-meet-scores/
(Can't post more than 2 links without 10 reputation points)

I apologize if I'm breaking rules of StackOverflow, but my searches online for "how to do" things with MySQL always lead me back here. I figured I'd sign up and ask questions.

Comment: You should post what your tables look like, what you have tried, and what you want to achieve. "State U. 31, Jackson Tech 12" does not have any meaning to me. Clicked your links makes a little more sense now

Comment: I haven't tried anything, except setting up a table with 14 columns of various data (team, score, division, rank for each), link to score, etc.

When I say "noob" I really mean it. I've only built MySQL tables in this case for the last two weeks. -- here's my scoreboard output table (from wpDataTables running the simple SELECT * FROM Scores1617 table in the database)
http://www.mattalkonline.com/2016-17-college-dual-meet-scores